# Resolve deferred when loop ends

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an async call inside a loop, and I would like to resolve the entire function when all the deferreds have been resolved.

```
var deferred = JQuery.Dferred();
for (var x in array){
    async(x).then(function(result){
       console.log(result);
    })
}
deferred.promise();
```

My question is: How could I make the deferred.resolve() when the loop has finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `when` with an Array of promises:

```
function waitForAll(array) {
    var promises = [];
    for (var x in array){
        promises.push(async(x).then(function(result){
           console.log(result);
           return result; // don't forget to propagate the result
        }));
    }
    return jQuery.when.apply(null, promises);
}
```

Use the magic variable `arguments` to get the results.

```
waitForAll(array).then(function () {
    var result = arguments;
    for (var index in array) {
        console.log(result[index]);
    }
}
```

jQuery's Promise library is messy at best (I'm sure they have their reasons). If you want to learn more about Promises look at Promises/A+ standard.

Comment: Thank you very much @Frits ! Is possible to return data when all the promises has been resolved?

Comment: Yes, see my updated answer. Make sure you propagate the result in your `then` though!

Comment: +1, but to be completely fair afaik the new jQueries are standards complaint, they're just very bad compared to the other implementations such as bluebird.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try .....

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();
for (var x in array){
    async(x).then(function(result){
       console.log(result);
       deferred.resolve(result);

    })
}
return deferred.promise();
```

Comment: I think it will be resolved when the first async call ends, not at the end of the loop.